# When I execute existsbyid(), I pass in the composite primary key object, and an error is missing

Tags: spring-data-jpa

#### The exception information is as follows

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [com.xxx.xxx.entity.xxxxKey@fb9c87cc] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106)
```

#### Jar package version and code location

`````
/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java:278````
`````

```
        query.setParameter(idAttributeNames.iterator().next(), id);
```

```
### Detailed description

When ID is a composite primary key object (only one property) an error will be reported
```

Comment: Please share code snippets of how your entity class is configured.