# How to delete/search existence by Composite Primary Key in Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**Scenario**

I'm having an Entity with a composite primary key as below. Also a repository with `exists` and `delete` operations using the `tokeId` composite key as below.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TokenId.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Token {

    @Id
    private String setId;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private long expiration;

    private boolean active;

    private boolean setActive;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface TokenRepositorySql extends JpaRepository<Token, TokenId> {

    @Transactional
    void deleteByIdIn(List<TokenId> id);

    boolean existsByIdAndActiveTrueAndExpirationGreaterThan(TokenId tokenId, long currentTimestamp);
```

**Issue**

In both delete and exists functions, hibernate fails to map `Id` as `TokenId`. Rather it's expecting a `String` id. Below is the exception.

```
Parameter value element [com.abc.security.token.repository.sql.entity.TokenId@458c58e3] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

**Workaround**

If I pass the values of the composite key separately in the repository, this seems to be working. But I want a way to use the composite key straightly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**P.S.**

I've also found this [unanswered question in the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029957/when-i-execute-existsbyid-i-pass-in-the-composite-primary-key-object-and-an).

Cheers.

Comment: The issue is probably the name of one of your composite primary key columns. It is called `id`. So when you try to use `deleteByIdIn` it is looking at this colum first (that is also why it expects a string). Have you tried renaming that one column?

Comment: @puelo, Thanks, this was true. When I renamed `id` field to `id2` that exception is gone. But now Hibernate can't figure out what `Id` is in `deleteByIdIn` method name. Wonder if there's a different way than `Id` to refer to the composite key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` annotations can serve the purpose here.

First, you can annotate your `TokenId` class with `@Embeddable` class level annotation as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class TokenId {

    @Column(name="field1")
    private String field1;

    @Column(name="field2")
    private String field2;
}
```

Then use the above Embeddable class as embeddedId in parent class as follows:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Token {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TokenId id;

    @NotNull
    private long expiration;

    private boolean active;

    private boolean setActive;
}
```